# Use allowJs only for type checking

Tags: typescript

I have a third-party library in `node_modules` that doesn’t include typings. There aren’t any on DefinitelyTyped either. When compiling, TypeScript complains about the missing typings. I can rectify that by adding a `.d.ts` that declares the module.

However, I figured out that the third-party library actually ships with complete JSDoc annotations that I want to leverage.

By adding the library to `include` and enabling `compilerOptions.allowJs`, the types are checked and enforced (and typings are also available in my editor). However, the library is also transpiled and output to the `compilerOptions.outDir`. I have not found a way to allow the JS to be used for type checking but not compilation.

As a workaround, I have set `compilerOptions.noEmit` and use a separate tsconfig that has `allowJs` set to false for compilation. However, that also requires me to use `// @ts-ignore` before the library import or else I get a warning in the compilation phase. Also, the solution seems kind of hacky to me.

Is there a way to drop this workaround and still use the JS for type checking?

Comment: I found the following issue, which tackles the problem from the other side (library authors), but is relevant nonetheless: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19145